# Voltage output across purely capacitive voltage divider when PWM/Square wave signal is applied?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pwm, capacitance

Having some trouble with understanding the voltage output in time domain across a capacitive voltage divider when applying a square wave from 0 to 5V? It can be assumed that the capacitors have some small series resistance.

I plotted the following circuit to better to see what would happen:
[image]

The below graph shows the time domain response of two capacitors in series. The brown curve represents voltage across C2 and the yellow curve represents voltage across C3.Note - C2 and C3 have a ESR of 5 ohms.

How and why does the the voltage across C3 become negative like that?

[image]

Comment: Are you thinking about this using entirely idealized components? Perfect capacitors and a perfect voltage source making a perfect voltage step in zero time? (Because, if so, the universe explodes and a new one is born. That's what happened the last time someone did this experiment, I hear.)

Comment: + you don't draw **any** current from the voltage divider, right?

Comment: Sparky, it might be *very* important to explain in which context you're asking this: an answer on a purely theoretical basis is one thing, but there's good reasons  not to do this in practice! (Exactly what jonk is pointing out: in a theoretical setting, the behaviour of this is undefined and might just as well destroy the universe, or convert you into a flower pot; in a real world, there's no such thing as a purely capacitive divider, nor an unloaded voltage divider, nor an ideal PWM or square wave voltage source)

Comment: I was looking first for the idealized situation. Hoping to then account for the situation in practice. If we introduced very small series resistance into both of the capacitors what would we be able to expect in that situation, since you are saying the ideal scenarion is undefined?

Comment: What trouble are you having - explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering perfect capacitors without ESR, ESL, leakage, etc, and applying the usual formula:

\$ i = C \frac{dv}{dt} \$

If the voltage step is also "perfect" then it has zero rise time, infinite slew rate and \$ dv/dt\$ and thus we have infinite current, which is inconvenient.

You can solve it with ideal capacitors by using a square wave signal with a non-zero rise time, so it has a finite \$ dv/dt\$. If the capacitors don't have any leakage and the simulated voltmeters draw zero current, then the actual value of rise time and \$ dv/dt\$ is irrelevant, it doesn't influence the result, if you want to use this methood you might as well pick 1V/s for convenience.

However it is easier to do the calculation with charge.

\$ q = Cv \rightarrow \Delta q = C \Delta V\$

Current is movement of charge, considering he charge q stored in a capacitor we have \$ i = \frac{dq}{dt} \$

Current is the same in both capacitors since they are wired in series

Therefore, charge in both caps will vary by the same amount \$ \Delta q \$.

This means the voltage in \$ C_2 \$ will vary by \$ \Delta V_2 = \frac{ \Delta q }{ C_2 } \$ and likewise for \$ C_3 \$ we get \$ \Delta V_3 = \frac{ \Delta q }{ C_3 } \$ ...

To get \$ \Delta q \$, note we have two caps of values \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ in series, that makes a combined cap of value \$ C = \frac{1}{1/C_2+1/C_3} = 148.5 pF \$ ; voltage over this cap C varies by \$ \Delta V \$ so

\$ \Delta q = C \Delta V = \frac{1}{1/C_2+1/C_3} \Delta V \$

Substitute that into the equations for each cap (\$ \Delta V_2 = \frac{ \Delta q }{ C_2 } \$)

and you'll get the answer, which is that both caps will share \$ \Delta V \$ in inverse proportion to their capacitance.

> Note - C2 and C3 have a ESR of 5 ohms.

This does not change the result. If the caps were leaky however, it would.

> How and why does the the voltage across C3 become negative like that?

Note that all the calculation was done using Deltas, which means there is an implicit gremlin lurking behind the scenes: **INITIAL CONDITIONS** ...

The initial condition of GND is known, and node "Vin" is set by the voltage source.

However, if both capacitors are ideal and have zero leakage, the initial condition of "Vmid" can be ... anything. If Vin is 0V, one cap can be charged to +1000V, the other to -1000V, so Vmid will be 1000V, but since both caps are charged to opposite voltages, in series they cancel out and you do get zero volts across both in series.

This is why, on this type of schematic, a simulator will either give an error like "Node Vmid has no path to ground" or "Can't determine initial condition for node Vmid" or something like that.

This means you have to specify the initial conditions yourself (via a spice directive) or add a path to ground for node Vmid, for example by adding capacitor leakage or a very high value resistor. Some simulators will "helpfully" add very high value resistors to ground at such nodes to make it possible to calculate the initial condition. But since it is done implicitly, it can be a bit... surprising.

In other words,

- Plot the voltages on separate graphs
- Do not look at the absolute values, only at \$ \Delta V \$ for each cap
- Be wary of a plot that starts with an edge because you never know what the initial condition was. Sometimes it helps to add a small startup delay to your voltage source so the plot starts with a flat line and you know the initial voltage.

For example, if the initial condition was Vin=5V and the simulator added a hidden resistor from Vin to GND, then the initial condition is 5V across C2 and 0V across C3... and when Vin goes down from 5V to 0V you will get a negative value on Vmid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is some series resistance to stop the Universe from exploding.

When voltage is applied across capacitors in series, the voltage splits in inverse proportion to their capacitance. The reason for this is that in a series circuit the same current flows through both capacitors, putting the same amount of charge in each. Since the formula for charge on a capacitor is \$q = CV\$, a smaller capacitor will have a higher voltage for the same charge.

With some resistance in series the current will start at a value set by the total resistance and applied voltage, and the capacitor voltages will rise exponentially - just like it does with a single capacitor. If the resistances are *internal* to the capacitors then their terminal voltages will have an initial step due to voltage drop across the resistance, but once they have fully charged their voltages will settle down in inverse proportion to their capacitance.

A good example of a practical capacitive divider is the 10x probe on an oscilloscope. At DC and low frequencies the division ratio is set to 10:1 by a 9MΩ and 1MΩ resistor. However at high frequencies the cable capacitance changes the division ratio, distorting the waveform. To compensate for this a trimmer capacitor set to ~9 times less capacitance than the cable is wired across the 9MΩ resistor, restoring the 10:1 division ratio.